# Neo4j - How to Ignore the pattern which has occurrence of same node more than once

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to Ignore the match patterns which has occurrence of same node more than once while query shortest path, example case in portrait in attached image.
[image]

Shortest path of A TO C gives,

```
start a=node:node_auto_index(point='A'),c=node:node_auto_index(point='c') match p=a-[r:CONNECTS*]->c return p;

1. A-> C
2. A -> B -> C -> A -> C
3. A -> B -> C
4. A -> C -> A -> C
5. A -> B -> A -> C
6. A -> C -> B -> A -> B -> C
```

and more of 9 pattern, but in some pattern same node or start and end node are appeared more than once which will be like irrelevant output, so how can i identify and ignore the pattern which has any node's more than once in its path.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: @jjaderberg version 1.9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found Solution for the above case

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(point='a'),
c=node:node_auto_index(point='c')
MATCH path= a-[r:CONNECTS*]->c
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(path) where 1=length(filter(m in nodes(path) : m=n))) 
RETURN path;
```

Now its resulting only the valid paths as expected :-)

```
1. A -> B -> C
2. A -> C
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use shortest path. The correct query is:

```
start a=node:node_auto_index(point='A'),
      c=node:node_auto_index(point='c') 
match p=shortestPath((a)-[r:CONNECTS*]->(c)) 
return p;
```

Or `allShortestPaths`

Comment: for above case both `shortestpath` and `allshortestpaths` are returning direct connection A -> C, but i need all possible valid connection like **A -> B -> C** and **A -> C**